# How to pass record id to another component while click on checkbox in aura iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputcheckboxes, iteration

I am facing one issue with navigating to record from another component when user selected checkbox in one component and I will get those selected `Id` in next component.

Comment: Please show what you have done and ask specific questions about that. This site is not to provide code where you do not seem to have done any research or work prior to asking the question. See How to Ask and How to Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can give **name** attribute to the checkbox and give the id of the record to it.
For example,

```
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" name="01p37000002uOCA" label="Select?" change="{!c.onCheck}"/>
```

In the **onCheck** method, you can access the ID as

```
var recordId = event.getSource().get("v.name");
```